# How do I keep an existing value and simply add something else along side it?

Tags: mysql

- Table: test
- Columns: column1 column2 column3

An already existing `row` has a `value` in `column3`.
I then want to do an `SQL update query` to that `row` and keep the already existing `value` and simply add another alongside it.

- Column3 datatype is `VARCHAR`

Is this possible?

Using `MySQL`

Comment: What datatype is column 3 ? if string then concat https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Comment: @P.Salmon Oh, sorry, forgot to mention that. It's a VARCHAR. It'll have something like, for example, `golden cardboard 114`. I'll then, probably, need to add something alongside it like `green cardboard 78`. End result will be `cardboard 114 green cardboard 78` and so on, depending on how many I add.

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks for the link, reading now.

Comment: Sounds like a terrible idea. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: @P.Salmon Oh. Darn it. I guess I have more reading to do. Thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE test
SET column3 = CONCAT(column3, 'additional value')
-- WHERE ...
```

Comment: I had no clue on the search term to use for this so I could find and read about it. Thank you for the example!